# Ajax.done returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I'm a newcomer to JS and Jquery, and I can't figure out how Ajax works for the life of me.
I'm working on a website with flask, and I need a way to send to pieces of data to a url, where they're appended to a list, after which a success message pops up.
However, I can't seem to get this properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

          $("#newPatternForm").on("submit", function(event){
                var setClass = document.getElementById("classes").value;
                var newPattern = $("#newPattern").val();
                $.ajax({
                    data:{
                        setClass: setClass,
                        newPattern: newPattern,
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/get_pattern",
                }).done(function(data){
                    alert("success")
                    var successMsg = "<p>Class: " + data + "<br>Pattern: " + data;
                    $("#newPatternFooter").append($.parseHTML(successMsg));
                });
            });
        });
```

The Flask code

```
@app.route('/get_pattern', methods=["POST"])
def get_pattern():
    set_class = request.form["setClass"]
    new_pattern = request.form["newPattern"]
    pattern_suggests.append([set_class, new_pattern])
    return set_class, new_pattern
```

I've tried several combinations while declaring successMsg, but all of them return at least one of them as undefined. How do I solve this?

Comment: What does `data` has ? Show output of that .